# Submitting forms on pages linked from a main page

Tags: groovy, webdriver

In this scenario, the main page contains a list of links to the subpages. The requirement is to navigate to each page (if a condition passes) and perform some actions.

I have written the loop using [Geb](http://www.gebish.org):

```
at MainPage
    ListItem.each {
        if(Button.present){
            Button.click()
            at SubPage
                SelectAddressButton.click()
                termsCheckBox.value(true)
                EnterButton.click()
                to MainPage
    }
}
```

I feel that the code can be improved so that the toMainPage need not be specified again inside the loop. I have alternatively used `driver.navigate().back()`  which doesn't seem clean either.